# jquery click() + load() doesn't work with Opera?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-click-event

I have made a jQuery/javascript that is loading a page into a div when clicking on a picture. It works for IE, Firefox, Chrome but **NOT Opera..** I can't figure out why it isn't working..

Please take a look on this page and click on a product to see how it loads a popup window.
http://www.dev.dressmind.com

Here is the script for the click:

```
function qp(id) { 
    $.ajax({
        method: "get",
        url: "QuickProduct.aspx",
        data: "id=" + id,
        //beforeSend: function() { $('#main').hide('slow').fadeOut(); },
        complete: function() { 
            $('#product-area').show('200').fadeIn(); 
            $("#product-area-overlay").show();
            $(".productbox-hover").hide();
        },
        success: function(result) { 
            $('#product-area').html(result); 
        }
    }); 
}
```

Then I have a link that look like this:

```
<a href="#" id="123123" onClick="qp(123123);return false;"><div></div</a>
```

SO please, can someone have a quick look and help me solve this problem.

**Solved it**

I solved it by moving the onclick-event to the div inside the   instead of having it on the link.

```
< a href="#" id="123123">
    < div **onClick="qp(123123);return false;"**> < /div>
< /a>
```

Comment: you can not start an ID attribute value with a Number , it is not valid

Comment: I solved it by moving the onclick-event to the div inside the <a> </a> instead of having it on the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside the fact that id's may not start with a digit as @Kanishka mentioned, you didn't post the code as you used it.

You are calling your function like this: `onclick="qp(id)"`. And unlike other browsers Opera (correctly) considers `id` an undefined variable. The other browsers are probably guessing you actually mean the `id` property of the current element. You need to use `onclick="qp(this.id)"` instead.

To get rid of the invalid IDs and repeating the onclick handlers, you should consider assignign the event handlers all at once. Something like this:

```
<a href="#" data-product-id="123456">...</a>
<a href="#" data-product-id="222222">...</a>
<!-- etc. -->

<script>
  jQuery("[data-product-id]").click(function() {
    qp(jQuery(this).data('product-id')); return false;
  });
</script>
```

BTW: What about non-Javascript users?

One more thing: You seem to using HTML5 features, but an XHTML Doctype leading to many validation errors.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips RoToRa! I solved it by moving the onclick-event to the div inside the <a> </a> instead of having it on the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning your event handlers through jQuery itself, rather than using the outdated `onclick` attribute:

```
<a href="#" id="123123" class="example">[image]</a>
```

```javascript
$(".example").click(function(e) {
    qp(this.id);
}

function qp(id) { 
  // ... your function...
}
```